# Create a Google Analytics filter to view stats from .com and .com.au domains separately

Tags: google-analytics, domains, analytics, country-specific

We are having trouble with distinguishing analytics for our dual domain.
Our website is currently set up as a .com that filters content for Australia/

We cannot seem to track .com.au's analytics data separately from the .com's.
Google search is ranking our pages from both .com and .com.au

Has anyone ever dealt with a dual domain setup like this? Is there a filter we can add to a new view to help us separate the two websites' data?

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by dual domain? This is not an industry term so please let us know more specifically what you mean. Do both sites have duplicate content? Are you redirecting users based upon locale? Do you use canonical tags? Have you set these two sites with individual GA accounts/properties?

Comment: If they were on separate GA properties or accounts, the data wouldn't be getting mixed.

Comment: The .com.au started out with the same content as the .com, but based on geo-location, the .com.au is served with blocks of content that the .com cannot see. 

The tracking code for the .com essentially tracks, both, the .com and .com.au, What I am struggling with is separating the .com data from .com.au's data.

Answer (score 2):

Base on your question and your comments, I will assume this is the right answer.

The best way to do this is by creating two different views. One for the .com and another one for the .com.au.

[how to add a new view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en)

Once you have created both views, you need to create a filter for each view specifying the *hostname*.

Use a predefined filter to Include only traffic to a particular hostname (in this case, as example.com or example.com.au)

[Check step 2 here](http://www.verticalrail.com/kb/filter-in-google-analytics-to-track-subdomains/)

In the above example they use a sub domain, replace that with your domain.

NOTE: you will need to wait up to 48 hrs to start seeing the data flowing separately in each view. Also, the data in the views will be recorded moving forward, you will not be able to see past data.

NOTE: in case you need to see past data in the “merged” view create two segments applying the same *hostname* filter approach for segments. There are plenty of online sources that you can follow.